# String s1=new String("demo"); While printing why does it give output as the given string?

Tags: java, string, class, constructor

If we create a `String` like below and print the value:

```
String s=new String("demo");
System.out.println(s);
```

...the output is:

```
demo
```

Good.  This is the expected output.  But here `String` is a class.  Remember that.  Below is another example.  For example, take a class like this:

```
class A
{
  public static void main (String args[])
  {
    A a =new A();
    A a1=new A("hi");  //we should create a Constructor like A(String name)

    System.out.println(a1);    //here O/P is address

  }
}
```

My doubt is that I created the `A` instance in the same way I created the new `String` object, and I printed that object.  So why does it not print the given `String` for the instance of `A`?

Comment: What is S.O.P? System.out.println()?

Comment: yes. ! @RichardTingle

Comment: Does that actually work, for me it just says Package S does not exist

Comment: PSVM, SOP? You'd post always post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @RichardTingle for me as well :P OP abbreviated it to SOP i guess.

Comment: Ok, in that case I'm going to correct this to real code

Comment: S.O.P-->System.out.println(); and PSVM --> public static void main()  sory for the short code

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the [`Object#toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) in your class. By default, the `toString()` method of Object is called.

Also, to print the value, you just need to override the method as internally a call will be made to the `toString()` method when this statement is executed.

```
System.out.println(a1);
```

Sample overriden `toString()` method.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    // return a string value
    return "The String representation of your class, as per your needs";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to `override` `toString()` method in your class the way you want to print something when call `System.out.println();`. In `String` class `toString()` method has override and you will get out put above due to that.

Comment: How can I do like c.toString() is enough in s.o.p(). are any other way . Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out already, **you need to override the default `toString()` method inherited from the `Object` class**. Every class automatically extends the `Object` class, which has a rather simple `toString()`, which can't know how to turn your particular object into a String. Why should it, especially if your class is arbitrarily complex? How is it supposed to know how to turn all your class's fields into a "sensible" string representation?

In the `toString()` of your class, you need to return the string that you want to represent your class with. Here is a simple example:

```
class A {
    String foo;

    public A(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return foo;
    }
}

public class sample {



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A("Hello world!");
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

String is a class whose purpose is to hold a string value and will return that value if referenced.  When you use other classes, you will usually want to add other behavior. If you want to use the class to hold different values that you can set (on object creation or later in processing) you may want to use "setter" and "getter" methods for such values.

Here is an example:

```
public class Snippet {
private static final String C_DEFAULT_VALUE = "<default value>";

private String name;
private static Snippet mySnippet;

public Snippet() {

}
public Snippet(String value) {
    setName(value);
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args != null && args.length > 0) {
        mySnippet = new Snippet(args[0]);
    } else {
        mySnippet = new Snippet(C_DEFAULT_VALUE);
    }
    System.out.println(mySnippet.getName());
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

}
```